# DHCP IPv6 and vendor-encapsulated-options

Tags: dhcp, ipv6, isc-dhcp

I was using this option on ipv4 to send some information to the host. On my host lease I have something like:

```
supersede vendor-encapsulated-options = "MY INFORMATION";
```

On the DHCP client host I can see an entry like that on the lease file:

```
lease {
  interface "eth0";
  fixed-address XXXXX;
  bla...
  bla...
  bla...
  option vendor-encapsulated-options "MY INFORMATION";
}
```

So I can get this information and do actions based on it.

Setting this entry on a IPv6 host entry on the DHCPD conf I can run the server with no error but the client is not getting the information. Looking at the tcpdump output I can't see this option is sent to the client in the Advertise from the DHCP Server.

How can I send vendor specific options to an IPv6 node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name has changed in `IPv6`it is called now `dhcp6.vendor-opts`. In the `dhcpd6.conf` file in the `host section` you must add:

```
option dhcp6.vendor-opts "options";
```

Depending on the client you must need to modify its config file to request it.